# Inserting a string of form "GUID1, GUID2, GUID3 ..." into an IN statement in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, guid

I've got a stored procedure in my database, that looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCountingAnalysisResults] 
    @RespondentFilters varchar
AS
BEGIN

@RespondentFilters = '''8ec94bed-fed6-4627-8d45-21619331d82a, 114c61f2-8935-4755-b4e9-4a598a51cc7f'''

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(600)

SET @SQL = 
   'SELECT *
    FROM Answer
    WHERE Answer.RespondentId IN ('+@RespondentFilters+'''))
    GROUP BY ChosenOptionId'

exec sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

It compiles and executes, but somehow it doesn't give me good results, just like the IN statement wasn't working. Please, if anybody know the solution to this problem, help me.

Comment: As an aside, you can always use a print @SQL to get a look at what the SQL statemtent looks like when it is executed.  Y0ou might find something there.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely look at splitting the list of GUIDs into a table and joining against that table.  You should be able to find plenty of examples online for a table-valued function that splits an input string into a table.

Otherwise, your stored procedure is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Consider the following value for @RespondentFilters:

```
@RespondentFilters = '''''); SELECT * FROM User; /*'
```

Your query would be more secure parsing (i.e. validating) the parameter values and joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM Answer
WHERE Answer.RespondentId IN (SELECT [Item] FROM dbo.ParseList(@RespondentFilters))
GROUP BY ChosenOptionId
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Answer
INNER JOIN dbo.ParseList(@RespondentFilters) Filter ON Filter.Item = Answer.RespondentId
GROUP BY ChosenOptionId
```

It's slightly more efficient as well, since you aren't dealing with dynamic SQL (sp_executesql will cache query plans, but I'm not sure if it will accurately identify your query as a *parameterized* query since it has a variable list of items in the IN clause).

Answer (score 2):

You need single quotes around each GUID in the list

```
@RespondentFilters = '''8ec94bed-fed6-4627-8d45-21619331d82a'', ''114c61f2-8935-4755-b4e9-4a598a51cc7f'''
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have closing quotes around your @RespondentFilters

```
'8ec94bed-fed6-4627-8d45-21619331d82a, 114c61f2-8935-4755-b4e9-4a598a51cc7f'
```

Since GUIDs do a string compare, that's not going to work.

Your best bet is to use some code to split the list out into multiple values.

Something like this:

```
-- This would be the input parameter of the stored procedure, if you want to do it that way, or a UDF
declare @string varchar(500)
set @string = 'ABC,DEF,GHIJK,LMNOPQRS,T,UV,WXY,Z'


declare @pos int
declare @piece varchar(500)

-- Need to tack a delimiter onto the end of the input string if one doesn't exist
if right(rtrim(@string),1)  ','
 set @string = @string  + ','

set @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
while @pos  0
begin
 set @piece = left(@string, @pos - 1)

 -- You have a piece of data, so insert it, print it, do whatever you want to with it.
 print cast(@piece as varchar(500))

 set @string = stuff(@string, 1, @pos, '')
 set @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
end
```

Code stolen from [Raymond Lewallen](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/10/26/133774.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need quotes inside the string too.  Try:

```
@RespondentFilters = '''8ec94bed-fed6-4627-8d45-21619331d82a'',''114c61f2-8935-4755-b4e9-4a598a51cc7f'''
```

You could also consider parsing the @RespondentFilters into a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Tank you all for your ansewers. They all helped a lot. I've dealt with the problem by writing a split function, and it works fine. It's a litte bit overhead from what I could have done, but you know, the deadline is hiding around the corner :)